# Does it matter which element I delete in a union

Tags: c++, destructor, unions

I am writing a translator and for that, I want to create a class Verb. this class should only save the complete cunjugation when it is irregular because it would produce large lists, taking much memory. So here's my code:

```
#include "string.h"  

struct Irregular{
    std::string present;  
    std::string simplepast;  
    std::string pastparticiple;  
}  

union Verbform{  
    Irregular* irregular;  
    std::string* regular;  
    Verbform(Irregular irreg){irregular=new Irregular(irreg);}  
    Verbform(std::string s){regular=new std::string(s);  
    ~Verbbform(){delete regular;}  //here is my problem  
}  

class Verb{  
    public:  
        //some public functions  
    private:  
        Verbform verbform;  
        //some other things;
}
```

When I do it like this and I initialize it with an irreglar verb, does he delete the complete irregular verb or only the first string?

When I do it like this:  `~Verbform(){delete irregular;}` and I initialize it with a normal string, does he deletes more than I want him to delete?

Comment: When the constructor initializes `Verbform::irregular`, the destructor invokes undefined behavior by way of accessing an inactive member of the union.

Comment: How are you going to ever use `Verbform`, without knowing which pointer is valid?

Comment: In class Verb, I have a member telling me which one is used and I can only use it when this member tells me I can.

Comment: How can I reduce the storage when there are later verbs needing about 30 different types of conjugaded forms, without using union or without having an undefined behavior?

Comment: Then make `Verb`'s destructor responsible for destroying the right member of the union. Or, use something like `std::variant`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`delete irregular` calls the `~Irregular()` destructor, which then calls the  `std::string::~string()` destructor 3 times.  Calling this when `irregular` is n not the active union member is *undefined behavior*.

`delete regular` calls the `std::string::~string()` destructor 1 time. Calling this when `regular` is not the active union member is *undefined behavior*.

You need to keep track of which member of the union is active so you can call the appropriate destructor, eg:

```cpp
enum Verbform_type { vtIrregular, vtRegular };

union Verbform_data {
    Irregular* irregular;
    std::string* regular;
};

struct Verbform {
    Verbform_type type;
    Verbform_data data;

    Verbform(Irregular irreg) {
        type = vtIrregular;
        data.irregular = new Irregular(irreg);
    }

    Verbform(std::string reg) {
        type = vtRegular;
        data.regular = new std::string(reg);
    }

    ~Verbform() {
        switch (type) {
            case vtIrregular:
                delete data.irregular;
                break;
            case vtRegular:
                delete data.regular;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, don't forget to follow the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) by adding copy/move constructors and copy/move assignment operators.

Otherwise, you should just get rid of your `Verbform` struct altogether and use [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) instead. Let it handle all of these details natively for you.

```cpp
using Verbform = std::variant<Irregular, std::string>;
```